# C++ using a struct as a argument for a class

Tags: c++, class, struct, header-files

I just cant work out how to get this working, theres another good question "Passing a struct as a constructor parameter in C++" which I though solved all my problems but I just dont get why my code is not working. I have three files namely: A source file

```
// A.cpp

#include "myClass.h"

int main()
{
    struct myStruct {
        double a; 
        double b; 
    };

   myStruct structName;
   structName.a = 1.1;
   structName.b = 2.2;

   myClass myClassObject(60.0, structName);

   return 0;
}
```

A class header file

```
// myClass.h

class myClass {
    private:
        double m_value; 
        double m_a; 
        double m_b; 

    public:
        myClass(double value, struct myStruct);
        ~myClass();
};
```

and another source file with the class definitions

```
// myClass.cpp

#include "myClass.h"

myClass::myClass(double S, const myStruct &s): m_value(S), m_a(s.a), m_b(s.b) {};
myClass::~myClass(){};
```

I get all sorts of errors, like in myClass source file I get Error: no instance of overloaded function "myClass::myClass" matches specified type.

Now if I remove

```
struct myStruct
{
    double a; 
    double b; 
};
```

from the A cpp source file and put it in the myClass header file, all the errors go away.

Q) Should the struct declaration go into the myClass header file, and be the only place I define this struct? is this the right way to code this?

Comment: your constructor signature is different in header and source: `myClass(double value, struct myStruct)` and `myClass::myClass(double S, const myStruct &s)`

Comment: Well your class needs to know what myStruct looks like, otherwise the signature of the constructor is incomplete and cannot be translated into code. So yes, it should be defined in the header.

Comment: It would help if you'd also post your entire compiler output log.
The one error you are mentioning about `no instance of overloaded function "myClass::myClass" matches specified type.` is most likely due to the fact that you declare the constructor as `myClass(double value, struct myStruct)` but implement it as `myClass::myClass(double S, const myStruct &s)`.

Comment: if I change S to value the error is still there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 2 solutions:

1. Put myStruct in myClass.h
2. Forward declare myStruct in myClass.h

Basically you need to ensure that when somebody reads (includes) myClass.h they also are made aware that myStruct exists and that everybody who needs myStruct can get access to it somehow.

You can't forward declare myStruct and then define it where you need it since that breaks the one-definition-rule, but you can have it in the myClass header or a dedicated header.

Comment: Generally it's good idea to have "structs.h" "commons.h" "enums.h" etc files in project to store all of such definitions

Comment: @MaciekGrynda Sometimes, but don't make it common unless you need to otherwise you may end up with everything knowing about everything and it becomes difficult to tell data types are for which class. Following the rules of encapsulation, you should try to keep the scope of everything as limited as you can. So here the OP only needs to declare the struct in myClass.h (as the code currently stands).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using only references and pointers to `myStruct` in headers the forward declaration would be enough.

```
struct myStruct; // < Forward declaration will cause 'incomplete type' error

class myClass {
    public:
        myClass(double value, const struct& myStruct); // < Passing by reference
        ~myClass();
}
```

But when you using the instance (or pass by value), then compile will require structure to be defined

```
// Forward declaration will cause 'incomplete type' error
#include "myStruct.h" // < Compiler should see full declaration of structure

class myClass {
    public:
        myClass(double value, struct myStruct); // < Passing by value
        ~myClass();
};
```

Comment: You didn't mention that in cpp where `myClass` constructor is defined he needs to have full declaration of `myStruct`. And if it (`myStruct`) is declared inside a function, it is function-local and cannot be seen outside of function's body.

Comment: @V.Kravchenko It is actually not needed if you are using only references and pointers without accessing members of the structure.

Answer (score 0):

Anywhere where you use myStruct (access an instance of it) you need to know the definition of it.

Since myStruct seems to be associated with myClass it makes sense to define it in myClass.h:

```
// myClass.h

struct myStruct {
        double a; 
        double b; 
    };

class myClass {
    private:
      :
    public:
        myClass(double value, struct myStruct);
        ~myClass();
};
```

You can even reduce the scope further, if it is specific to myClass then you can make it a member of myClass, then you need to explicitly use the full type `myClass::myStruct` to access it. I like this when a struct is very specific to one class because you are forced to use its full name and won't get namespace conflicts or such things.

```
// myClass.h

class myClass {
    public:
        struct myStruct {
            double a; 
            double b; 
        };

        myClass(double value, struct myStruct);
        ~myClass();
};
```

And then use it in main.cpp like:

```
// A.cpp

#include "myClass.h"

int main()
{   
   myClass::myStruct structName;
   structName.a = 1.1;
   structName.b = 2.2;

   myClass myClassObject(60.0, structName);

   return 0;
}
```

In myClass.cpp you use the full type:

```
// myClass.cpp

#include "myClass.h"

myClass::myClass(double S, const myClass::myStruct &s): 
    m_value(S),
    m_a(s.a),
    m_b(s.b)
{};
```

Answer (score 0):

What Sorin said. Additionally, you can forward declare the class and use its pointer, this will require no actual "#include" if I am not mistaken.